# Python handling a TypeError:

Tags: python, exception

I'm getting a:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

error as my program is querying my db. The problem is that it then halts my whole program which I don't want happening for the web application.

Instead how could I handle this gracefully, as it must refer to a empty field and I'm not to concerned about it. This is a code fragment:

```
try:
    if not doc['coordinates']:
        xxxxxxxxx
    else:
        xxxxxxxx

except (ValueError, geocoders.google.GQueryError):
    pass
```

I've tried including a `TypeError` in the `except()`, but that causes problems on the client side.

Thanks

Comment: What is `doc` supposed to be? It is `None` now.

Comment: What problems on client side do you get when including TypeError?

Comment: It's the result of a db query.

Comment: @Himanshu I'm using highcharts and it stops rendering points on the graph....seems to hang and get this message in console: this.renderTo.removeChild(container); // do not clone this highcharts

Comment: Can't you just add `TypeError` to the `except`'s arguments? i.e. `except (TypeError, ValueError, geocoders.google.GQueryError)`?

Comment: @martineau, I tried but it gave client side errors with the highChart library, and seemed to just be looping on the server.

Comment: If you can figure out something to prevent the client side error that occurs when `doc` is `None`, you could add a separate `except NoneError:` after the one you have and follow it with code to does whatever preventing the error requires to be done.

Answer (score 2):

How about this :-

```
if doc:
    try:
        if not doc['coordinates']:
            xxxxxxxxx
        else:
            xxxxxxxx

    except (ValueError, geocoders.google.GQueryError):
        pass
```

Or this :-

```
    try:
        if not doc or not doc['coordinates']:
            xxxxxxxxx
        else:
            xxxxxxxx

    except (ValueError, geocoders.google.GQueryError):
        pass
```

Comment: I thought that to would have worked but it gives me an error with my google geopy api.

Comment: Thanks, but with both I still get the same problems as above. .

Comment: In which case I can't help as this requires a better understanding of your specific problem